# fancybox not called on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to use Fancybox in my asp.net mvc view on page laod  and using this example 6 at http://fancybox.net/blog

My html is:

```
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">

        <div id="main">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/FancyBox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/FancyBox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog-user-login").trigger('click');       
    });
</script>

<div id="dialog-user-login">
    I am here
</div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

but fancybox is not called on page load. Is there anything missing in my code ?

[**Edited**]

tried this but didnt work as well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-user-login").fancybox({
        'showCloseButton'   : false,
        'titlePosition'         : 'inside',
        'titleFormat'       : formatTitle
    });
$("#dialog-user-login").trigger('click'); 
  });
```

Comment: i guess you should call the plugin first

Comment: I don't see any fancybox code. Try reading this, in particular steps 4 and 5: http://fancybox.net/howto

Comment: @thordarson my fancybox  css and js files are in same folder. I dont see any error in Firefox console.

Comment: You're not initializing fancybox by calling fancybox().

Comment: @thordarson, I used '@codeiz' suggestion and it is not working even.

Comment: you have to be sure what version of fancybox you are using, could you confirm? ....because if you are using fancybox 2 it requires jQuery v1.6 or later and you seem to be using v1.5.1

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I don't think you can use the event "click" on a div. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

when using a jquery plugin you should call it on the element you want ..

here is how you do it for fancy box

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-user-login").fancybox({
        'showCloseButton'   : false,
        'titlePosition'         : 'inside',
        'titleFormat'       : formatTitle
    });
$("#dialog-user-login").trigger('click'); 
  });
```

Comment: I used your code but it didnt work. am I missing some file(s) or order of files is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

as much as i wanted to post this as a comment...

anyway, to DotnetSparrow, I've just recently made a site myself and implemented fancybox, and it works fine.

On ex. 5 & 6, I tried it on my page and it works fine too.

your html lacks a lot, as others have commented, the blog you based it from are snippets, and not the whole set of instruction...

follow the following:

1.Follow the **first paragraph** of this instruction first: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions

2.In HTML

```
<a id="urLink" title="Login" href="#dialog-user-login">Login Here</a>  
<div id="dialog-user-login" style="display:none">
    I am here
</div>
```

3.In javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //attach fancybox on ur <a> tag
    $("#urLink").fancybox({
        'scrolling' : 'no',
        'titleShow' : false,
        'onClosed'  : function() { $("#login_error").hide(); }
    });

    //if you want to show the login in fancybox on load
    $("#urLink").trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: the OP seems to be using fancybox v1.3.4

Comment: probably, since I can only comment here, I suggest OP to use the updated version instead: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 0):

a little late but i hope this answers any similar question:

```
$(function() {
    $.fancybox.open([{
        //o $("#myDiv").html() aunque este ultimo muestra los datos en bruto 
        content: $("#myDiv").text()
    }]);                
});
```